# Symbol not found: _NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb

Tags: ios, iphone, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to run the app with XCode 7.0 on iPhone 4 with iOS 7.1.1 and get the following error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb
Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/2076134C-C83B-4BBC-B6B4-41D5DD078704/tasks.app/tasks
Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
in /var/mobile/Applications/2076134C-C83B-4BBC-B6B4-41D5DD078704/tasks.app/tasks
```

Previously deployment target of project and target was iOS 8.0 but now I've changed it to iOS 7.0 and I also did changes for properly working at iOS 7.0 and higher. I didn't realize that it won't even run on device and can't understand how to resolve this issue. Can it be because of my XCode version?

P.S. desktop OS is Yosemite (10.10.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb` (for Handoff) came in with iOS 8.

If you look at NSUserActivity, you'll see:

```
/* The activity type used when continuing from a web browsing session to either a web browser or a native app. Only activities of this type can be continued from a web browser to a native app.
*/
@available(iOS 8.0, *)
public let NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb: String
```

Comment: But I'm not using `Handoff`. Where is `NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb` stored?

Comment: are you using "`NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb`" in your code anywhere?

Comment: no, it was in library and I already removed it but problem is still here

Comment: try doing a clean build (and/or removing the "`Derived Data`" folder) and see what happens